# Issues importing a custom toolbox within another custom tool

Tags: arcgis, arcpy

I'm trying to call on a custom python script within another script. Everything works fine if I run the script standalone outside of ArcGIS, but if I try to make it a custom tool with parameters, it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jamil.harvich\Documents\ArcGIS\Python_Scripts\Working\IP_Anno\Script\Script_Part1.py", line 80, in <module>
    arcpy.ConcatenateRowValues_AA(lyr[0] + '_Intersect', 'SHORT_DESC', 'NAME', lyr[2], '-')
  File "C:\Users\jamil.harvich\Documents\ArcGIS\Python_Scripts\Working\IP_Anno\ConcatenateRowValues101.tbx", line 54, in ConcatenateRowValues
    /jVXV+BHwwJ5+Gfgv/wnbP8A+NV2Eo+ZTjHPQ9qlR60cIvojBSkupxw+Avwvz/yTTwX/AOE7Z/8A
AttributeError: Object: Tool or environment <ConcatenateRowValues_AA> not found

Failed to execute (Script).
```

Thanks. I hope the question is clear. If you need me to specify anything, just ask.

Comment: Are you sure ConcatenateRowValues_AA is a function on arcpy (I can't find it)? What version of ArcGIS are you?

Comment: @Jambo313. What release of ArcGIS are you working with?

Answer (score 0):

Before calling it, in your script you should import the Toolbox that contains your tool "ConcatenateRowValues_AA", with the command:

```
arcpy.ImportToolbox(TOOLBOX_PATH)
```

where TOOLBOX_PATH is the absolute path to your .tbx file.